# Project Size increases drastically with Android Studio 2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import, android-studio-2.0

I was having a project in `Android Studio 1.5` and it's size was about 19 Mb and when I imported same project in `Android Studio 2.1` it's size increases to 51 Mb.
Size difference is **around 14 times**. This is way too much.
 I want to know what can be the possible reason for this increase in size and can we do something to decrease size?

Comment: Probably google bload. That is they probably had to make the thing searchable and it's all an 'index' now.